# Can't find android sdk 2.3.4 in SDK manager

Tags: android, sdk, emulation

I'm having problems finding the 2.3.4 sdk in the Android SDK Manager download list. I updated the SDK tools to r11 and my platform-tools to r5 but 2.3.4 won't show up. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out  [Android 2.3.4](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.4.html#)

API Level

"The Android 2.3.4 platform does not increment the API level — it uses the same API level as Android 2.3.3, API level 10.

To use APIs introduced in API level 10 in your application, you need compile the application against the Android library that is provided in the latest version of the Google APIs Add-On, which also includes the Open Accessory Library.

Depending on your needs, you might also need to add an android:minSdkVersion="10" attribute to the  element in the application's manifest. If your application is designed to run only on Android 2.3.3 and higher, declaring the attribute prevents the application from being installed on earlier versions of the platform.

For more information about how to use API Level, see the API Levels document."

Comment: Well my 2.3.4 phone behaves differently (opengl) from my 2.3.1 tablet. The emulator 2.3.1 and 2.3.3 look just like the tablet. so 2.3.4 is different after all...

Answer (score 3):

Google didn't release 2.3.4 into the SDK because it contains only bug-fixes. It doesn't add or change any APIs, so there is no need for an update on 2.3.3.

Comment: Well shoot, I need an API level 11 feature and was hoping 2.3.4 had it because that's the min level I need to target.