# Google Api level 10 project not working on android 2.3.4

Tags: android, eclipse, api, usb

I created a project to implement USB accessory. The accessory mode is supported for Google API level 10 which works on Android 2.3.4.
Now my project works on AVD which has target device as Google APIs level 10 but does not work if I change the target to 2.3.3 ( Since **2.3.4 target is not there on eclipse)**.

In short **I want to run a project that uses Google API level 10, on an android phone. How to do this?**

I tried copying the .apk file but that was of no use. I also tried to copy the complete project but this is also not working for me.

Please assist...

Answer (score 1):

I guess the obvious answer (though not the one you're looking for, I suspect) is that you'll need to get a device that's running 2.3.4 or higher (my current RAZR MAXX is at 2.3.6).  A device that's running a version lower than 2.3.4 can't be asked to run an app compiled for versions 2.3.4 and higher.

and this may (or may not) be helpful to clear things up as well:
[Can't find android sdk 2.3.4 in SDK manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399068/cant-find-android-sdk-2-3-4-in-sdk-manager)

Welcome to Stack!

Comment: @ Dredel: as I mentioned earlier, I have Samsung Galaxy Ace that is running on 2.3.6 platform. I have gone through that link but that link was of no use as the issue has not been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, USB accessory does not work with 2.3.3, only with 2.3.4 and up. (And it does only work on selected phones, of course.)

Comment: I have a phone with android platform 2.3.6 but it does not work there also. Please suggest.