# Making Google Api level 10 project run on android 2.3.4/6

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api, android-sdk-2.3

How to run an android project that uses Google Api level 10 on android 2.3.4 Or 2.3.6???

I have the android device but the project is not running?

Do I have to do something special?

Comment: what do you mean by *not running*? What error are you getting?

Comment: Please refer this: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html It might help you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are more likely to get a helpful response if you include relevant code and the logcat errors. So if none of the current answers have helped please provide more information.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911486/google-api-level-10-project-not-working-on-android-2-3-4
Here you fill find the complete problem detail.

Answer (score 3):

so you are using sdk 3.1.x for project development and wants to test it Android device which having 2.3.x

no you can't do that because

```
project min target SDK should be less or equal (<=) to the device os version
```

see this line in you manifest file (**API 8 is sdk 2.2***)

```
<uses-sdk android:minsdkversion="8">
```

and for enable debug the project on real device make sure you should define this in you project file

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

in you application tag.
like this

---

```
<application android:debuggable="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">  
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MainActivity">  
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">  
            </category></action></intent-filter>  
        </activity> 
    </application>
```

---

let me clear if still have doubt about this.

Comment: you are completely getting it wrong my friend. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911486/google-api-level-10-project-not-working-on-android-2-3-4
Here you fill find the complete problem detail.

Answer (score 1):

to run application on your device you will need your device's usb drivers and put your device on development mode.